# java.io.InvalidClassException: local class name incompatible with stream class name "void"

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While trying to write a spark sql dataframe to jdbc I get the following exception:

```
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:918)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply$mcV$sp(DataFrame.scala:1444)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1444)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1444)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.foreachPartition(DataFrame.scala:1443)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.saveTable(JdbcUtils.scala:276)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:311)
  at .....
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: java.lang.Void; local class name incompatible with stream class name "void"
```

This is the way the dataframe is saved

```
dataFrame.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url, tableStatement, new Properties)
```

Previosly this kind of exception were being solved by having the function return a certain value, but now it's out of our control.
Anyone encountered this before?

Comment: this seems more like a issue caused by older jars in your build path. Have you checked whether you have only the latest jars ?

Comment: I did update to make sure I have the latest, using spark 1.6.2 and scala 2.11.8. I'm going through the dependencies to see if I missed anything.

Comment: Dix you fix this? i'm facing the same